# .Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, access-violation

I've met a really strange problem.

The code is as follow:

```
::boost::shared_ptr<CQImageFileInfo> pInfo=CQUserViewDataManager::GetInstance()->GetImageFileInfo(nIndex); 
Image* pImage=pInfo->m_pThumbnail;
if(pImage==NULL)
    pImage=m_pStretchedDefaultThumbImage;
else
{
    //
    int sourceWidth  = pInfo->GetWidth();
    int sourceHeight = pInfo->GetHeight();

    int destX = 0,
        destY = 0; 

    float nPercent  = 0;
    float nPercentW = ((float)GetThumbImageWidth()/(float)sourceWidth);;
    float nPercentH = ((float)GetThumbImageHeight()/(float)sourceHeight);

    if(nPercentH < nPercentW)
    {
        nPercent = nPercentH;
        destX    = (int)((GetThumbImageWidth() - (sourceWidth * nPercent))/2);
    }
    else
    {
        nPercent = nPercentW;
        destY    = (int)((GetThumbImageHeight() - (sourceHeight * nPercent))/2);
    }

    int destWidth  = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
    int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);
    rcShowImage=CRect(rc.left+destX, rc.top+destY,rc.left+destX+destWidth,rc.top+destY+destHeight);
}
ASSERT(pImage != NULL); // passed assertion...
graphics.DrawImage(pImage,rcShowImage.left,rcShowImage.top,
rcShowImage.Width(),rcShowImage.Height()); // problem happened here.
```

I received the following exception:

```
First-chance exception at 0x004095b0 in ec.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefef2.
Unhandled exception at 0x004095b0 in ec.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefef2.
```

I have checked the `pImage`, I am sure when `graphics.DrawImage` is called, it is not `NULL`.

- why such a problem happened?
- What is `0xfeeefef2`?

Answer (score 11):

`0xfeeefeee` is a fill pattern that the debug version of the Windows heap (not the C runtime heap) uses for uninitialized memory. `0xfeeefef2` is `0xfeeefeee+4`. It sounds like you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer located in (or copied from) a block of memory allocated from the heap.

The debug heap automatically gets enabled when you start your program in the debugger, as opposed to attaching to an already-running program with the debugger.

The book *[Advanced Windows Debugging](http://www.advancedwindowsdebugging.com/)* by Mario Hewardt and Daniel Pravat has some decent information about the Windows heap, and it turns out that the chapter on heaps is [up on the web site as a sample chapter](http://www.advancedwindowsdebugging.com/ch06.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
pImage=m_pStretchedDefaultThumbImage;
```

Is there a possibility that m_pStretchedDefaultThumbImage is uninitialized?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if `pImage == NULL` on the third line you pasted? In that case, `rcShowImage` is not assigned a value.

Comment: It looks like rcShowImage is on the stack (members accessed with "."), so accessing it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: True, but we don't know what type it is and whether the constructor does anything sensible.