# C++ program takes a very long time on function return

Tags: c++, performance, stl, destructor

I have a function that was written by someone else and I have determined that it can sometimes take a very long amount of time to step out of the function after it has fully executed every statement within the function block.  If I recall correctly, the only thing that happens during this time is all destructors on the stack (local) objects are called and then the function returns as the stack pointer is moved.  I would like to post the function, but it's a bit complicated and the intellectual property of someone else.  However, only standard STL containers are declared on the stack.  The containers are

```
set<unsigned int> 
unordered_map<unsigned_int, vector<unsigned int>>
vector<pair<set<unsigned int>,set<unsigned int> > >
vector<pair<set<unsigned int>,int> >
set<unsigned int>
several unsigned ints
unordered_map<unsigned int, unordered_map<unsigned int, bool> > 
set<unsigned int>
set<unsigned int>
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?  I'm thinking that the time might be consumed by destructor calls on the locally-declared STL objects.  Has anyone seen this happen before?  Anywhere else I should look?

Comment: How much data is in the containers?

Comment: The destruction of `int`s is trivial and `vector`s have only one deallocation to make. However, `set`s are typically implemented with N nodes to hold the data and therefore have N deallocations to make which can be very costly when put together. (can't comment on `unordered_map` in this regard)

Comment: You can test if its the destructors by `.clear()`ing all the structures at the end and timing that

Comment: @immibis, I'm not exactly sure / haven't checked yet, but perhaps a lot.  But executing the function up to the destructor calls doesn't take very much time.  Why would it take significantly more time to destroy an object than to insert data in the object?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, that's a good idea...I'll try that.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should tell us the compiler you're using, and whether this is a "debug" (unoptimized) version of your program.  If this is Visual Studio, the debug version of STL has a **lot** of iterator checking going.  If you are using a debug version, create a release version and run that version and compare.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I was using Visual Studio 2010, debug build with the following compiler flags: /nologo /FD /Od /W3 /MDd /EHa /Ob0 /Oy-

Answer (score 2):

Without actually posting source code, I realize that this answer might be a bit vague or anecdotal.  But I'll give credit to vu1p3n0x for the helpful suggestion which led me to understanding where time was being consumed.  It was actually the destructor on this data structure:

```
unordered_map<unsigned int, unordered_map<unsigned int, bool> > somemap;
```

Calling somemap.clear() in some cases takes a very long amount of time.  I have observed cases of it taking longer than 5 mins.  So I guess the lesson here is to be careful when nesting unordered_maps which may grow large.

EDIT: The code does run much faster in release mode.  It's still the case that the above data structure is relatively slow, but it's much less slow in release mode vs. debug mode.

I later found this topic which I think is more helpful to anyone who happened to stumble upon this question:

[Weird behaviour of C++ destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532092/weird-behaviour-of-c-destructors)

Comment: How certain are you of your findings? I can't imagine that the map that takes little time to create would take much longer to destruct...

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein, You might be right, I edited my post above.